# How to set theme dynamically coming from server ANDROID

Tags: android, colors, themes

I am getting color codes in from server and I have to set those as my theme. I know I can do it by individually setting colors on each element. Is there any way to create a theme dynamically or declare colors of theme programmatically.
The main aim is like a group of users can set their own theme.

```
  private void setColors(COLORS color) {
  int toolbarColor = 0;
  int statusbarColor = 0;
  switch (color) {
      case GREEN:
          setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Green);
          toolbarColor = R.color.green;
          statusbarColor = R.color.greenDark;
          break;
      case RED:
          setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Red);
          toolbarColor = R.color.red;
          statusbarColor = R.color.redDark;
          break;
      case BLUE:
          setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Blue);
          toolbarColor = R.color.blue;
          statusbarColor = R.color.blueDark;
          break;
  }
  mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, toolbarColor));
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, statusbarColor));
  }
}
```

Currently, I am doing something like this but as modules, in project increases, I find it difficult or hectic to do it like this. So I am looking for something else like setting theme colors programmatically.

Thank you all in advance for helping me out

Comment: What does your AppTheme and (for example) AppTheme_NoActionBar_Blue look like?

Comment: Basically my app has toolbar floating action buttons dividers in recycler views and also want to change the color of Labels that(Color) has already been defined under res->values->colors file

Comment: So you have a limited set of colors from which users may choose?

Comment: No it could be anything Admin or users itself can select those colors

Comment: @Android How did yo achieve, what you have asked, I have the same requirement